# select rows/columns dynamically in excel

Tags: excel-2007, rows

I m trying to select rows/columns using vba. I want to pass row numbers through a textbox `Rows("2:5").Select`
Here 2 and 5 shall be passed as variables..Once passed the rows shall be selected and copied to a specified location in the same sheet. I m new to excel and learning using macros. May someone pls suggest a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the script for copying .... 
(your can pass the row numbers as arguments and concat them as String)

```
Rows("1:13").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Suppose you want to paste to some other sheet

```
Sheets("Sheet2sa").Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Insert Shift = xlDown
```